# Pandas - create multi value fields after merging two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a python script that merges to csv tables according to keys / foreign keys. Since the relation is sometimes `1 : n` my output data contains a new row for each n.

What I want is a single row with multivalues fields in the new foreign key column.

Some example data for better understanding:

CSV1

```
cid;name;surname;address
1;Mueller;Hans;42553
2;Meier;Peter;42873
3;Schmidt;Micha;42567
4;Pauli;Ulli;98790
5;Dick;Franz;45632
```

CSV2

```
cid;ticketid
1;9
1;22
2;8
3;7
4;6
5;5
```

Desired output:

```
cid;name;surname;address;ticketid
1;Mueller;Hans;42553;[9;22]
2;Meier;Peter;42873;[8]
3;Schmidt;Micha;42567;[7]
4;Pauli;Ulli;98790;[6]
5;Dick;Franz;45632;[5]
```

My current merge code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('kunde.csv', sep=';', header=0, dtype=object)
df2 = pd.read_csv('tickets.csv', sep=';', header=0, dtype=object, na_values='')


df = (df1.merge(df2, left_on='cid', right_on='cid', suffixes=('', '_B'), how='left'))
```

I found some examples on how to do it with group by. But an additional problem for my case is that the script needs to be somewhat generic and I need to assume that I only know the names of the two ID columns I perform the join on and not all column names. So most of the examples do not work for my case or create multi values fields for all non ID columns

Comment: Can you explain more? In `df2` are multiple columns?

Comment: Yes in my ``df2`` are multiple columns but I just need to transfer all matching keys into a new column in ``df1``

Comment: OK, I add more general solution, I hope it is what you want.

Comment: The second solution seems great on first try. I will test and reply with feedback. Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `list`s per groups:

```
df1['ticketid'] = df1['cid'].map(df2.groupby('cid')['ticketid'].apply(list))
print (df1)
   cid     name surname  address ticketid
0    1  Mueller    Hans    42553  [9, 22]
1    2    Meier   Peter    42873      [8]
2    3  Schmidt   Micha    42567      [7]
3    4    Pauli    Ulli    98790      [6]
4    5     Dick   Franz    45632      [5]
```

EDIT: More general solution with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and aggregate all columns to `list`s:

```
print (df2)
   cid  ticketid  A
0    1         9  s
1    1        22  r
2    2         8  t
3    3         7  r
4    4         6  m
5    5         5  a

df = df1.join(df2.groupby('cid').agg(lambda x: x.tolist()), on='cid', rsuffix='_B')
print (df)
   cid     name surname  address ticketid       A
0    1  Mueller    Hans    42553  [9, 22]  [s, r]
1    2    Meier   Peter    42873      [8]     [t]
2    3  Schmidt   Micha    42567      [7]     [r]
3    4    Pauli    Ulli    98790      [6]     [m]
4    5     Dick   Franz    45632      [5]     [a]
```

Comment: The second solution works great! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti - Glad can help, nice weekend!